# Use saved midi presets without using a computer

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, live, pc

I've got a novation impulse 49 MIDI keyboard, and I'd like to use it live with presets that I have created on logic, but it would be such a pain and also kinda dangerous to bring my macbook with me every time I play live.

Does anyone know of any device which could sync with your DAW, which you can save instrument presets to and then plug the device into your MIDI keyboard somewhere else and it recognises the presets and you can just use it with the device rather than your PC.

Thanks

Comment: could this help you?https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001182090-Live-9-Playing-Software-Instruments

Comment: If I was playing somewhere where it was dangerous to bring my keyboard/computer rig, I'd reconsider where I was playing...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sync with your DAW"? The only way to use Logic live is to have a computer running Logic with you. Another option is to use Apple MainStage which is their live version of Logic, and it's only $30. But you'll have to use a Mac for it in either case.

Comment: Get a cheaper laptop, or a Raspberry Pi of you're technically inclined.

Comment: @ToddWilcox my understanding was that the OP wanted something that could load logic plugins and their presets - something like what the Seelake can do for VST plugins, or the Mod Duo for LV2 plugins. (Is that right OP?). Are Logic Plugins basically audio unit?

Comment: @topomorto All included Logic virtual instruments use the AU API, but they have certain settings associated with them that only work in Logic. It’s weird. A Logic virtual instrument is more than an AU plugin and preset. There are other metadata and additional controls that Logic brings in when you load an Apple virtual instrument. Those same elements are also available in MainStage. IIRC, you can use the Apple sampler and a couple other Apple AU plug-ins in other DAWs, but reconstructing all of the experience you get in Logic is nigh impossible.

Comment: @ToddWilcox interesting - sounds like what the OP is after is not possible. (mind if I expand that into an answer?)